# Работа с документами MS Office (Word, возможно Acces) C# - подскажите что почитать?

Tags: c#, office

Имею большой пробел в своих знаниях. Подскажите литературу.

(Стартовая задача такова. Имеется несколько файлов ворд содержащих множество вопросов для тестирования. Необходимо их прочитать, распарсить (вероятно по стилям), создать из них новый документ.)

P.S. О msdn я в курсе, но в нем можно закапаться надолго, а хотелось бы что то вроде шпаргалки для быстрого старта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю [этой статьи](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) будет более чем достаточно.

Comment: в msdn можно закапаться надолго, а хотелось бы что то вроде шпаргалки для быстрого старта